# Why can't I use this.arguments, while arguments work?

Tags: javascript

```
function MyArray() {
    var self = this.arguments; //<---
    this.toString = function() {
        return self;
    };

}

var c = new MyArray(2, 3, 1, '232');
console.log(c.toString());
```

> > undefined

```
function MyArray() {
    var self = arguments; //<---
    this.toString = function() {
        return self;
    };

}

var c = new MyArray(2, 3, 1, '232');
console.log(c.toString());
```

> > [2,3,1,'232']

So, why is that so? What is the difference between **this.arguments** and **arguments**?

Comment: You must have arguments defined in a different scope, so it may help if you show that also.

Comment: Are you assuming that `this` in JavaScript represents something that it represents in a different language?

Comment: Please explain first why it should work since `this.arguments` and `arguments` do not look equal to me in any way

Comment: @amnotiam: I used to, but maybe I am again.. I know that `this` in JavaScript represents the scope, but here.. functional scope, instead of block scope as in C#, Java and etc... I am trying to access the instance's `this.arguments` but I guess that doesn't work??

Comment: @Esailija can you explain what you mean further? Doesn't `arguments` permeate through the new instance also? I'm new in JavaScript here..

Comment: @JanCarloViray: That's the trouble then. In JavaScript, `this` is a concept entirely separate from scope. That's why you can refer to the `arguments` variable *(which is declared automatically)*, but it isn't available on `this`.

Comment: @amnotiam: hmmm.. another paradigm shift for me.. please enlighten me with a link or your own words :)

Comment: @JanCarloViray: In JS, `this` represents *"calling context"*, which can be set a number of different ways. It varies based on *how* a function is called. If I do `my_obj.myMethod()`, then `this` will refer to `my_obj`, whereas if I do `var m = my_obj.myMethod; m();`, the value of `this` usually changes to the `global` object. There are several other ways `this` is set. I'll find a link.

Comment: @amnotiam Thank you very much! If you would write your answer in the Answers section, I will make yours the Best Answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS, `this` represents "calling context", which can be set a number of different ways. It has really nothing to do with variable scope. They're entirely separate concepts. That's why `arguments` is available as a variable, but not a property of `this`.

The value of `this` varies based on how a function is called.

---

***Called as a method***

For example, if I do...

```
my_obj.myMethod();
```

...then `this` will refer to `my_obj` because the function `myMethod` was called from the context of `my_obj`.

---

***Called independently as a function***

but if I do...

```
var m = my_obj.myMethod;
m();
```

Even though `my_obj` and `myMethod` are the same code as the first example, the value of this will usually change to the `global` object.

---

***Called using `.call` or `.apply`***

There are several other ways `this` can be set as well.

```
m.call(my_other_obj, "more", "args");

m.apply(my_other_obj, ["more", "args"]);
```

Using `.call` or `.apply`, the first argument passed becomes the value of `this`. The difference between the two is how the rest of the arguments are passed.

---

***Created using `.bind`***

There's also `.bind()` which takes arguments in the same manner as `.call()`, but creates and returns a new function with the `this` value and any other arguments permanently set.

---

***Called using the `new` operator***

The final way is when you call a function as a constructor. To do this, you use the `new` operator.

```
var new_obj = new m;

var new_obj = new obj.m;
```

In both cases, the value of `this` will be a new object being constructed. YOu should never use `new` unless the function called has been set up to be used as a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `this.arguments`. However `arguments` is an array-like object which [always exists inside functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and refers to the arguments given in the call.